# Concentrate data frame information in r

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
> df1
      2013-04-1 2013-04-2 2013-04-3 2013-04-4 2013-04-5 2013-04-6 2013-04-7 2013-04-8 2013-04-9 2013-04-10 2013-04-11
bin_1        32       489        32        32       364        19       312         0         0          0        346
bin_2         8       346         8         0        98         8        12        12        46        364        346
bin_3         9        98       346        46         9       312         6      1912         0        489          0
bin_4         4        12         9        12         0        12         0       987         9         19         12
bin_5         0         0         8         8         0         0       312         6       312         12          4
```

df1 contains 5 rows (bins) and 23 columns (date)

```
> df2
           orange apple pear banana watermelon lemon
2013-04-1       1     1    1      1          0     1
2013-04-2       1     1    0      1          0     0
2013-04-3       1     1    1      1          0     1
2013-04-4       0     1    0      1          1     1
2013-04-5       1     0    0      0          1     1
```

df2 contains 23 rows(date) and 6 columns (types of fruits)

So now, I want to concentrate these 2 dfs into 1 big data frame that contains all the information, like:

```
> df3
      orange apple pear banana watermelon lemon
bin_1      ?     ?    ?      ?          ?     ?
bin_2      ?     ?    ?      ?          ?     ?
bin_3      ?     ?    ?      ?          ?     ?
bin_4      ?     ?    ?      ?          ?     ?
bin_5      ?     ?    ?      ?          ?     ?
```

But how can i concentrate the data? So for example,

1. on 2013-04-1,
2. bin_1 contains 32 fruits, bin_2 contains 8 fruits, ..., bin_5 contains 0 fruits (based on df1)
3. only orange, apple, pear, banana, and lemon are available (based on df2)

**Q. I want my df3 to contain concentrate information, like bin_1 on average contain x amount of oranges, ...etc .How can I model this?**

Code:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(`2013-04-1` = c(32, 8, 9, 4, 0), `2013-04-2` = c(489, 
346, 98, 12, 0), `2013-04-3` = c(32, 8, 346, 9, 8), `2013-04-4` = c(32, 
0, 46, 12, 8), `2013-04-5` = c(364, 98, 9, 0, 0), `2013-04-6` = c(19, 
8, 312, 12, 0), `2013-04-7` = c(312, 12, 6, 0, 312), `2013-04-8` = c(0, 
12, 1912, 987, 6), `2013-04-9` = c(0, 46, 0, 9, 312), `2013-04-10` = c(0, 
364, 489, 19, 12), `2013-04-11` = c(346, 346, 0, 12, 4), `2013-04-12` = c(0, 
9, 12, 46, 489), `2013-04-13` = c(32, 8, 19, 46, 0), `2013-04-14` = c(0, 
987, 12, 0, 6), `2013-04-15` = c(0, 346, 4, 346, 0), `2013-04-16` = c(0, 
1912, 1912, 12, 364), `2013-04-17` = c(12, 98, 32, 32, 1912), 
    `2013-04-18` = c(12, 12, 12, 0, 346), `2013-04-19` = c(9, 
    46, 98, 312, 4), `2013-04-20` = c(32, 987, 46, 9, 312), `2013-04-21` = c(4, 
    98, 12, 32, 12), `2013-04-22` = c(19, 0, 4, 346, 0), `2013-04-23` = c(1912, 
    364, 0, 0, 489)), row.names = c("bin_1", "bin_2", "bin_3", 
"bin_4", "bin_5"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(df2)
structure(list(orange = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), apple = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), pear = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0), banana = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), watermelon = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), lemon = c(1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
)), row.names = c("2013-04-1", "2013-04-2", "2013-04-3", "2013-04-4", 
"2013-04-5", "2013-04-6", "2013-04-7", "2013-04-8", "2013-04-9", 
"2013-04-10", "2013-04-11", "2013-04-12", "2013-04-13", "2013-04-14", 
"2013-04-15", "2013-04-16", "2013-04-17", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-19", 
"2013-04-20", "2013-04-21", "2013-04-22", "2013-04-23"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: For example, on 2013-4-01, the fruits in bin1 could be 1 orange + 2 apples + 3 pears + 4 bananas + 22 lemons, 4 oranges + 5 apples + 6 pears + 7 bananas + 10 lemons, 3 oranges + 3 apples + 4 pears + 8 bananas + 14 lemons, and so on. There are just too many possibilities. I think you need some other constraints on the combinations of fruits.

Comment: @ekoam Exactly! This is what i'm struggling about. i'm guessing if equally distributed of the fruits will help.... I basically want to combine two dfs into 1 without losing much information.

Comment: If that's the case, you will get something like 6.4 oranges on 2013-4-01. Are you sure this is what you want? Or perhaps just do a random split?

Comment: @ekoam my end goal is to convert df3 into a heatmap to show the relative amount of fruits in each bin. If I do the avg, do you think it can keep it consistent?

Comment: Nope. You will definitely get different heatmaps if using different approaches (e.g random/equal) to split the bins. And a random split will likely cause the heatmap to change every time you run the code.

Comment: @ekoam So taking the average will be my best approach?

Comment: My whole point is that there is no way to keep your results consistent across different splits. We can force the fruits to be equally distributed and then plot the heatmap, but that absolutely doesn't mean we will get the same heatmap if we give, for example, heavier weight to oranges than to the other fruits. In this sense, the relative amount of fruits in each bin cannot be determined. With only the data you provided above, you have to subjectively choose the distribution you want. That's entirely up to you.